# how to load different css for different pages?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create different style sheet for my pages.

I have a set header file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
       <link href="/includes/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
</head>
<body>
```

then I have my main body page, I will have `main.html, project.html, contact.html` …etc

```
//php load different pages for my body
<div>….
```

and a footer page.

```
<footer>…
```

My question is how to swap the css file to adapt different pages for my main body page. The header and footer files are the template and I don't want to change the css file every time I load a new page. How do I accomplish this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using PHP to include your header and footer files into each html file? You could use a PHP variable in each html file that tells the included header/footer which page you're viewing. Then load the appropriate CSS file dynamically based on that variable's value.

Comment: use require.js which helps in asynchronous loading

Answer (score 2):

One simple way of doing it is by using a php function called "basename".

If you have 3 pages main.php, project.php and contact.php, you can load different resources depending upon the name of the page you are viewing.

For example
echo ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'main.php'){ ?>
     <link href="/includes/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
   <?php }
   elseif(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'project.php'){
   ?>
    <link href="/includes/project.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
   <?php } ?>
 </head>
<body>
```

Comment: Probably a good solution, but why the if/elseif stuff? Why not just extract the filename without extension and add `.css` instead? Do it dynamically.

Comment: Ya either is possible. I just thought this would be simpler for him to understand.